# What happened to Balak?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, historical-figures, parashat-balak

What ever happened to Balak after the Bil'am affair? Bil'am is referred to often as Bil'am HaRasha' (the wicked), and he is blamed for the entire encounter [as well as the Ba'al Pe'or incident](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9959/showrashi/true). But wasn't Balak to blame for conceiving of the idea of cursing Bnei Yisrael? I thought the Ba'al Pe'or idea was the Plan B of that effort, which I'd think would at least give him a share of the blame there as well. Did he repent? Do we know anything of his descendants?

Comment: Bil'am is also killed in the later war with Midyan.

Comment: Isn't there a midrash about Ruth coming from him?

Comment: @IsaacMoses, [Horiyos 10b.](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=28&daf=10b&format=pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Hat tip to [jake](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/489/jake) for his [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27019/what-happened-to-balak#comment62582_27019) above regarding what became of Balaq's descendants. The Talmud Bavli in Masekhet Horayot (10B) states ([Original](http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_36089_18.pdf), [English](http://halakhah.com/pdf/nezikin/Horayoth.pdf)):

> בשכר מ"ב קרבנות שהקריב בלק הרשע זכה ויצתה ממנו רות דאמר רבי יוסי ברבי חנינא רות בת בנו של עגלון בן בנו של בלק מלך מואב
>
> As a reward for the forty-two sacrifices which the wicked Balak offered he gained the privilege of having Ruth descended from him; for R. Jose son of R. Hanina said: Ruth was the daughter of the son of Eglon who was the son of the son of Balak, King of Moav.

Comment: Whoa, that means that Dawidh HaMelekh is a descendant of Balaq!

Comment: That concept should not surprise you any more than the notion that Mashiach will be a descendant of two "Illegal" birth directions.  By being a descendant of Peretz - who was born by Yehuda having relations with his daughter-in-law, and by Ruth, a descendant of Moab who is the son of one of Lot's daughters having relations with her father.